# Django Ajax Button - When I move the JS logic for the button to a separate file, the button can't find my Django link

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I've got a follow button working well when included in the  tag in the HTML for the specific page I want to use it for:

```
function toggleFollow(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'user_follow' view.kwargs.username %}",
        success: function(data) {
          $("#followCount").html(data.follower_count + ' Followers');
          $('#followElement').html(data.button);
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error){
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
  };
```

But when I move this button to a separate file, I get the django error that "The current path  didn't match any of these" and then it lists all of my paths. How do I call my django url inside of my button.js file?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use django template tags in the `button.js` file.  You have to pass the url from the template to javascript function.

For example you can add the following code to your template file:

```
<script>
    window.USER_FOLLOW_URL = "{% url 'user_follow' view.kwargs.username %}";
</script>
```

And then use this variable in the button.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.USER_FOLLOW_URL,
    ....
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. There's no way to add this variable into my base template, right? Because certain other pages wont have the django variable so it throws an error. I can only have it on the specific pages I need?

Comment: Yes, `view.krargs.username` is unavailable in other pages, so `{% url %}` will throw an exception.  You can place this code to the base template and wrap it with `{% if view.krargs.username %}` but this solution has no much sence.